# Beamer class: Footnote in titlepage

Tags: beamer, footnotes

If I use `footnote` in the titlepage, the name in the footnoteline also gets a footnote sign. How can latter be avoided?

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\makeatletter
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Berlin}      
  \usecolortheme{crane} 
  \usefonttheme{serif}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
  \setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}
  {
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}
      \insertframenumber{}% / \inserttotalframenumber
      \hspace*{2ex} 
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\title[Topic short]{Topic long}
\author{Name\footnote{thank you for funding me}}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\thanks` command instead of footnote in titles and names etc.
Also added a way to change the symbol in thanks that get from here:
https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=16568
(@Stefan's answer)

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\makeatletter
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Berlin}      
  \usecolortheme{crane} 
  \usefonttheme{serif}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
  \setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}
  {
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}
      \insertframenumber{}% / \inserttotalframenumber
      \hspace*{2ex} 
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\title[Topic short]{Topic long\thanks{test}}
\author{Name\thanks{thank you for funding me}}%Here is the problem fix
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
%Add in case you want other symblo
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\@fnsymbol}[1]{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or *\or \dagger\or \ddagger%\or
%    \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger
%    \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}}
%\makeatother
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edited: You need the change on \thefootnote that had removed. Found after a second run**

Answer (score 4):

You can use a short author `\author[short version for footline]{long version for title page}`

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\makeatletter
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Berlin}      
  \usecolortheme{crane} 
  \usefonttheme{serif}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
  \setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}
  {
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}
      \insertframenumber{}% / \inserttotalframenumber
      \hspace*{2ex} 
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\title[Topic short]{Topic long}
\author[Name]{Name\footnote{thank you for funding me}}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```